# Last-N days Pandas DataFrame TimeGrouper

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

---

I got a DataFrame which has date as index, and I would like to do operation "Get the sum of latest 2 days" on each day:

```
            A
2015-11-01  1
2015-11-02  3
2015-11-03  2
2015-11-04  4
2015-11-05  1
2015-11-06  2
```

The aims is:

```
       Lastest_2_days_A
2015-11-01  1
2015-11-02  4   
2015-11-03  5
2015-11-04  6
2015-11-05  5
2015-11-06  3
```

I thought TimeGrouper might help. However when I use TimeGrouper and set freq to be "2D":

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

rng = pd.date_range('2015-11-01', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,1), index=rng, columns=["A"]).applymap(lambda x:int(x))
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq="2D", closed='right')).sum()
```

The result would be :

```
            A
2015-10-30  1
2015-11-01  5
2015-11-03  5
2015-11-05  2
```

It is obvious that in TimeGrouper there is not any overlap between index in the result, while what I need is to perform the latest N-days sum operation for each day. Does it possible to do this operation? Any suggestions will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple case like this, `shift` will suffice:

```
In [6]:

print df

            A
2015-11-01  1
2015-11-02  3
2015-11-03  2
2015-11-04  4
2015-11-05  1
2015-11-06  2

In [7]:

print df + df.shift(1).fillna(0)

            A
2015-11-01  1
2015-11-02  4
2015-11-03  5
2015-11-04  6
2015-11-05  5
2015-11-06  3
```

More generally, it is a case of `rolling` apply, `min_periods` control the minimal window that will be considered as valid. Skipping it in this case will result in having `nan` for the 1st cell:

```
In [8]:

print pd.rolling_sum(df,window=2,min_periods=1)

            A
2015-11-01  1
2015-11-02  4
2015-11-03  5
2015-11-04  6
2015-11-05  5
2015-11-06  3
```

Comment: Thanks CT, rolling is exactly what I want